# Get message body using fetch

Tags: javascript

In jquery, I could do this:

```
    $.ajax({
    url: "my_sharepoint_site",
    type: "post",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "contentType": "text/xml"
    },
    success: function(data){
        var m = data.d.GetContextWebInformation.FormDigestValue;

    }
});
```

I'm trying to get that same response data by using fetch.

```
fetch("my_sharepoint_site", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "contentType": "text/xml"
    }
}).then(function(response){

    // response doesn't contain 'd'

});
```

I can't seem to figure out how to get the rest of the data. I'm sure it's something absurdly simple.

Comment: Where is the XML you claim to be posting?

Comment: Use the debugging tools in the browser. Are any error messages shown on the console? Are the requests the same?

Comment: The contentType header can probably be removed as I'm not actually sending anything. It was part of another example I pulled for making sharepoint REST calls.  

Both execute fine without error and receive the same response from the server. However, the fetch doesn't include the message body within it's response like the ajax call does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` does not automatically parse JSON responses. You have to do so explicitly.

See [the example on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch);

```
fetch("my_sharepoint_site", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "contentType": "text/xml"
    }
}).then(function (response) {
     return response.json();
}).then(function(data) {
    // data should contain 'd'
});
```

Comment: Yes that's it. Thanks.  I looked into that but apparently was using it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explore the `.json()` method :

```
fetch("my_sharepoint_site", {
    method: "post",
    headers: {
        "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "contentType": "text/xml"
    }
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => console.log(data));
```